# custom control on flowlayoutpanel - selected item

Tags: c#, events, custom-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have a custom control that I load up in a flowlayoutpanel control and it displays fine, but im having a little trouble figuring out where to handled the "selected" aspect of things. its sort of a two part problem.

one is that i need the control to act as a single object (its a display control, no buttons etc) so now if you click on a label in the control, it doesnt trigger the controls onclick.

the other part is, how do i get the selected item?

Right now i have a List<> of my custom class objects (the data) and the custom control's constructor can take one of these items, i think loop that list and create the flowlayoutpanel

```
Foreach(CItem item in MyItems)
{
flowlayout1.controls.add(new MyControl(item))}
```

in the Enter/Leave events of the control i have it change the background color, and i need to update a Selected some place but im not sure where is best

I also tried to wire the same event for all controls in the custom control

```
    public MyControl(CItem mv)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            ctrl.Enter +=new EventHandler(MyControl_Enter);
            ctrl.Leave +=new EventHandler(MyControl_Leave);
        }

    ........
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Bindable FlowLayoutPanel that included setting the selected index (with highlighting depending on the selected control.  I posted it over on the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/binding-flowlayoutpanel) site.  Check it out and let me know if that works for you.